# Get parent page node for component in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I configured a listener in the magnolia observation module that uses `info.magnolia.module.observation.commands.RestrictToNodeTypeEventListener` for `mgnl:component` node type. When a `NODE_ADDED, NODE_MOVED, NODE_REMOVED, PROPERTY_ADDED, PROPERTY_CHANGED and PROPERTY_REMOVED` event happens on the `mgnl:component` it triggers a custom command class.
In the custom command class the node is of type `mgnl:component` and the path is for example:  node at path `/aalongpubname/de/test-page-for-observer/content/01` but I need to get the parent `mgnl:page` node for it (ie. /aalongpubname/de/test-page-for-observer). The component could also be nested ie. not at the first level. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I don't really get the question, can you elaborate it further, please?

Comment: I hope I explained better in the description above @Ducaz035

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one of the way to do this is: `NodeUtil.getNearestAncestorOfType(node,"mgnl:page").getName()`

Comment: Indeed :) congrats